# Can a hotel or Airbnb host deny me accommodations based solely on the fact that I will be having a medical procedure?

Tags: disabilities

An Airbnb host recently denied me accommodations because I will be recovering from surgery. It happens to be a very simple procedure, but even if it wasn't, isn't this a violation of the American with Disabilities Act? I'm not asking for wheelchair access or any other special features. However, if the listing fulfills my needs, and it does, isn't it illegal for them to deny my reservation based on that consideration alone?

Airbnb hosts can deny guests for a number of reasons, but they made it explicitly clear in their messages (stored by Airbnb) that the only reason for their denial is the fact that I'm having surgery.

Comment: I don't believe AirBnb hosts need to abide by the ADA, or are subject to the same restrictions as hotels. They can deny you for just about any reason because they are a private party (not a Christian? Weird hair? Saw a facebook post that had alcohol?). Hotels on the other hand may have to abide by the ADA/discrimination laws because they are businesses/corporations.

Comment: The ADA is a civil rights law that prohibits discrimination against individuals with disabilities in all areas of public life, including jobs, schools, transportation, and all public and PRIVATE places that are open to the general public. https://adata.org/learn-about-ada

Comment: Private meaning "owned by something other than the government", a private individual has no obligation to abide by the ADA. For example I don't *have to* install a ramp into my house for disabled individuals for the off-chance one may stop by, but a *private business* may have to. Your last sentence sums it up... "private places **that are open to the general public**", a private home is not open to the general public, even if that person advertises the place on Airbnb. Somebody can't walk in off the street and ask to pay to stay the night.

Comment: As soon as a listing is on Airbnb platform, it's no longer private. Technically, any corporation that is privately owned is the same thing.

Comment: A lawyer in the city where this occurred just wrote the following: It sounds like disability discrimination in violation of the Fair Employment and Housing Act, the Unruh Act and Los Angeles Municipal Code Ch. IV, Art. 5.5, § 45.52. StackeExchange is cool, but most of the people here aren't experts.